# Action On Google - Smart Home - "Couldn't update settings please check your connection”

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I authenticate my Smart Home action with `WS Cognito`, after login I see "Account now linked" for a few seconds but where browser closes I see "Couldn't update settings.

Please check you connection".

I view Log on `Stackdriver` but there is nothing, from AWS I see that the lambda containing the SYNC is not called.

Comment: Are you sure the fulfillment URL you provide to Google is correct and available? Have you checked it via other tools? Such as curl or postman.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it via Postman. It is strange though that nothing comes out of the google logs.